# Getting old behavior after compiling and starting

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, sfml

I previously set up this project to test SFML, and it worked so I deleted that code and copied and pasted code from another project that I had made(made a new source file and two new headers).

But for some reason oblivious to me, once I build it with my new code it outputs the SFML test still..

[image: Screenshot]

**Also:** if I *click Build -> Clean Solution*, it completely messes up my entire project and stops generating .exe files for some reason even though the build was successful.

**Things i have tried**:

- Removing all the files and replacing them.
- Restarting Visual studio.
- Putting other code in, still the same outcome.

Its probably a small problem..

EDIT:

```
int main() {
sf::RenderWindow window;

sf::Vector2i centerWindow((sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width / 2), (sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height / 2));

window.create(sf::VideoMode(900, 900), "JUMP TEST", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);
window.setPosition(centerWindow);

window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);

//Player Object:             
Player player({ 40, 40 });
player.setPos({ 50, 500 });

//Coin Objects:
std::vector<Coin*> coinVec;
Coin coin1({ 20, 20 });
Coin coin2({ 20, 20 });
coinVec.push_back(&coin1);
coinVec.push_back(&coin2);

coin1.setPos({ 150, 300 });
coin2.setPos({ 300, 300 });

//Score Objects:
int score = 0;
int wSize;
sf::Font arial;
arial.loadFromFile("arial.ttf");

std::ostringstream ssScore;
ssScore << "Score: " << score;

sf::Text lblScore;
lblScore.setCharacterSize(30);
lblScore.setPosition({ 10, 300 });
lblScore.setFont(arial);
lblScore.setString(ssScore.str());

//Gravity Variables:
const int groundHeight = 720;
const float gravitySpeed = 1.0;
bool isJumping = false;
bool buttonPressed = false;

//Main Loop:
while (window.isOpen()) {

    sf::Event Event;

    const float jumpSpeed = 100.0f;
    const float moveSpeed = 1.0f;

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) {
        player.move({ moveSpeed, 0 });
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) {
        player.move({ -moveSpeed, 0 });
    }

    //Event Loop:
    while (window.pollEvent(Event)) {
        switch (Event.type) {

        case sf::Event::Closed:
            window.close();

        case sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed:
            if (Event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Key::Space)
            {
                isJumping = true;
                buttonPressed = true;
                player.move({ 0, -jumpSpeed });
            }
            break;
        case sf::Event::EventType::KeyReleased:
            if (Event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Key::Space)
                isJumping = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;

        }
    }

    //Gravity Logic:
    if (player.getY() < groundHeight && isJumping == false && buttonPressed == true) {
    player.move({ 0, gravitySpeed });
    }
    //Player Collision
    if (player.getY() >= 500)
    {
        player.setPos({ player.getX(), 500 });
        isJumping = false;
    }

    //Coin Logic:
    for (int i = 0; i < coinVec.size(); i++) {
        if (player.isCollidingWithCoin(coinVec[i])) {
            coinVec[i]->setPos({ 422234, 423432 });
            score++;
            ssScore.str("");
            ssScore << "Score " << score;
            lblScore.setString(ssScore.str());
        }
    }


    window.clear();
    coin1.drawTo(window);
    window.draw(lblScore);
    coin2.drawTo(window);
    player.drawTo(window);
    window.display();
}
```

}

Comment: Well, rather than showing us a screenshot you should most likely show as the actual code of your main loop. It's possible you're using some uninitialized value that's set to 0 by compiling a debug built, which then could screw something up.

Comment: Are you sure you actually build what you think you build? Try doing a clean and full rebuild.

Comment: i added the code but as i said i tried putting completely different code in and it still gives me the same outcome. When i do a clean and full rebuild it then says that it cannot find the .exe and i have to start the whole project again.

Comment: Based on your error output, the compile failed. When this first happens in VS it gives you the option to run the program anyway, or not. If you run the program anyway It will run the previous successful build, so when you clean, that goes away. Fix the errors in the output window and make sure compilation succeeds before debugging

Comment: Ending up reinstalling visual studio.. and that somehow has fixed my problems but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot shows an error. So your program did not build at all.

Visual Studio then gives you the option to run an old version from the last time it compiled. I guess this is what you do. *Never* click yes. You don't want this. I have no idea who thought this would ever make sense.

Make sure your program compiles without errors. You should see the correct program then.

Comment: This is the correct answer, VS is telling you that element1 needs to be cast as a float as it cannot be converted automatically into an int. Visual studio is running the last instance of a correct build that has been cached and saved somewhere.